# Calling Page Click event via User Control

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, user-controls, response.redirect

I am working on a project in which I am binding Cart:

[image]

As shown in image I am populating my cart. Using User Control. And in User control I have populated that using One simple aspx form that is minicart. So now as you can see there is one button `Checkout` in That page. Which is populated through User Control but actaully its inside my minicart form. So now if I am trying to redirect using that `Checkout` link button. But that is not calling my click event rather its just postback the page.

[image]

Basically I want to call aspx page's click event through user control in my another aspx page.

I have tried to call that click event through many ways. But still page is only doing `postback`. I just want `respose.redirect` to my checkout page.

Even I have tried by using `<a>` also:

```
<a id="lnkcheckout" runat="server" href="javascript:return false;" 
      onclick="checkout_onclick">Checkout</a>
```

But not succeed..

Comment: u will hav to raise the event

Comment: using eventhandler???

Comment: @SagarS.Dhanorkar- i have searched that option too.. but that will work when that button is on your user control... here my scenario is button is on minicart.aspx page and i am binding it to user control.

Comment: Use Page.PreviousPage Property with Server.transfer

Comment: @RamdasBhosale- its not working... Still page is postback..

Comment: @RonakBhatt bro plz go through this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3  might be helpful

Comment: @SagarS.Dhanorkar- how it is possible in my case... as in that link it is calling click event of button that is in same page...

Comment: I don't get it where you stuck actually you just want to redirect then just write `respose.redirect` no need to fire the click event

Comment: i have done it... but still i am getting this it automatically include postback there

Comment: What type of postback still not get it tell me simple steps where you stuck

Comment: @dholakiyaankit- i have updated my question please check

Comment: Where you are populating your products?

Comment: in Page called products.aspx... in which i took user control...

Comment: Why you need to call a usercontrol for checkout button only/

Comment: no that control is used in 3 pages... thats why.. else i had thought about point you are saying

Comment: Which thee pages? that can be repeated
But see you can take one anchor tag also <a href="checkout.aspx">your linkbutton will be acted as span </a>  and that's all

Comment: i have tried that one also... as i have displayed it in my question... but still its coming `javascript:__dopostbach('checkout','')`

Comment: oh god not like that check my comment properly
`<a href="checkout.aspx"></a>` No need to cause postback

Comment: `<a id="lnkcheckout" href="checkout1">Checkout</a>` still getting the same thin...

Comment: ammm what same thing you are getting not getting redirected?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46207/discussion-between-dholakiyaankit-and-ronak-bhatt)

Comment: as shown in second image.. _dopostback is automatically coming

Comment: `<div align="right" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                     <a id="lnkcheckout" href="checkout1">Checkout</a>
</div>`

Comment: its not coming like that... its automatically calling this operation..

Comment: Which operation :( :(

Comment: thanx for help @dholakiyaankit and others as i got the asnwer.. i dont know how but after taking only anchor tag its now working for me...

Comment: Its working? don't tell me i will fire you

Comment: yah its working... i have tried same earlier but it was giving me the same thing ..  now i its working... i think you have done some magic here in my code... :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't go for a server side for only redirecting you can take one achor tag also

```
<div align="right" style="padding-top: 10px;"> <a id="lnkcheckout" href="checkout1">Checkout</a> </div>
```

And it will work  :) I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) or use `return false` like ,

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery(document).on('click','.morebutton', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('ok');// you code in place of alert;
    });
});
```

Comment: Will it work?? As i am showing this button on aspx page whcich is binded through user control and user control is binded through another aspx page. So basically i want to call aspx page's click event through user control in my another aspx page.